# Populating a field by comparing the string from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one containing the keywords and another table containing string values. I want to add a column where the reference to first's table id will be inserted.
This inserted value will be on the basis where the string on first row will be taken and will be checked if it contains any of the keywords from the other table and if a keyword is found contained in the string then insert the id of that keyword here (which should contain foreign key constraint).

I am confused as to how this can be achieved. Should be a procedure or trigger as this field should be populated on after insert. I am trying a trigger but am not able to work out the string functions.

I'm new to SQL and learning, so tried INSTR() but it takes only first keyword.

Also which way would be best and fast as both the tables contains around 10000 values each.

one table is sports containing

```
id - sport
```

other table is funlocater containing

```
id - countryid - tag - link - email - sportid
```

The data in funlocater is populated manually except the sportid part which should be populated autmatically.

eg.
a row in funlocater contains

```
1 - 183 - skatebording competition at tawar mall - www.abcd.com/abcd?xyz - abcd@abcd.com - ???
```

now the sportid should contain the sportid from sports table after checking the keyword skateboarding if contained in the string of tag column of funlocater.

which would be like `INSTR('skateboarding', funlocater.tag)`
But I want to check all the values which matches best.
How do i do the matching work? `INSTR()` does the work but takes only one value. I want to check if a keyword is found then insert the sports.id or else check the next keyword.

Comment: Please edit your question and post sample data and desired output based on it

Comment: This sounds like a many:many relationship.  A string can contain many keywords.  A keyword can be used in many strings.  The usual way to deal with this is to add another table, containing string_id, keyword_id pairs, not merely another column.

Comment: Thanx guys for the help.... and yes Paul this is many to many relationship. Means you suggest that I create mapping table that contains the sportid and the funlocater.id where skateboarding is found in the funlocater.tag?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to say that you better normalize your db schema and store your mappings in a table like

```
CREATE TABLE funlocater_sports 
(
    funlocater_id INT NOT NULL, 
    sports_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY pk_funlocater_sports(funlocater_id, sports_id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_funlocater(funlocater_id) REFERENCES funlocater(id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_sports(sports_id) REFERENCES sports(id)
);
```

Nevertheless you can achieve your immediate goal with the query like this

```
UPDATE funlocater l JOIN
(
  SELECT f.id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.id) sport_ids
    FROM funlocater f JOIN sports s
      ON FIND_IN_SET(s.sport, REPLACE(f.tag, ' ', ',')) > 0
   GROUP BY f.id
) q ON l.id = q.id
   SET l.sportid = q.sport_ids
```

This way you'll get comma separated list of sport ids from `sports` table in `sportid` column of `funlocater` table.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdaf1/1)** demo

If you then want to use triggers then it's better to factor out common code in a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION tag_to_sportid(atag VARCHAR(512))
RETURNS VARCHAR(512) 
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN
  (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.id)
        FROM (SELECT 1 id) f JOIN sports s
          ON FIND_IN_SET(s.sport, REPLACE(atag, ' ', ',')) > 0
       GROUP BY f.id
  );
```

And then triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_funlocator_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON funlocater
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.sportid = tag_to_sportid(NEW.tag);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_funlocator_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON funlocater
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.sportid = tag_to_sportid(NEW.tag);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed0b3/1)** demo

Comment: @sachalsain Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Thanx so much boss, but unfortunately couldn't work on it cuz of my fever. But will surely check it out today and get back to you

Comment: This worked great, just one thing want to know is that GROUP_CONCAT() makes comma separated values, then again you used REPLACE() to convert spaces to commas. but when I remove the REPLACE() i get nulls, why is that? I dont want to use REPLACE() eg if I add 'Dodge Ball' in the sports.sport and similarly add the same thing in the funlocater.tag, then it fails.

Comment: @sachalsain Well you need some sort of a delimiter to split your `tag` to terms. If you use a space in terms and as a delimiter between them there is no way to tell one from another.

Comment: I did something like this | I created a mapping table sportmap then inserted using this INSERT INTO  `sportmap` ( `sportid`,`funlocaterid`) SELECT s.id, f.id FROM funlocater f, sports s WHERE INSTR( f.tag, s.sport ) This did the matching and inserted all the values. My confusion is that funlocater table don't need to retain values, so I create the table daily and destroy it and same will happen for the sportmap table. For this I need a trigger that whenever I create the funlocater table the sportmap table is emptied and new values gets populated. (Is my approach OK? or stupid?) |